# Doing a exercise about bunny colony, hit a wall

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was doing last exercise from this list (its called graduation): http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/ but had one major problem. The code I wrote runs, but it will crash at so time (after deleting half bunnies), sometimes after program deletes half bunnies first time, sometimes after 10 such cycles, note that i havent implemented alot yet because i want to fix this bug, with your help of course. Also I know this is not code review, but some small tips about style and improving would be good too. So this is code i wrote so far:

Main.cpp:

```
include bunnyList.h
include windows.h

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    bunnyList Colony;
    int turns = 0;
    Colony.setUp();
    while(Colony.getColonySize() > 0){
        //New turn
        Colony.increaseAgeAndKill();
        Colony.breedBunnies();

        std::cout << "Turn: "<< turns << ". Colony size: " << Colony.getColonySize() << std::endl;
        //Get rid of these food eaters
        if(Colony.getColonySize() > 1000){
        std::cout << "500 bunnies died!" << std::endl;
        Colony.killHalfBunnies();
        }
    Sleep(100);
    turns++;;
    }
}
```

bunnyList.h:

```
#ifndef BUNNYLIST_H
#define BUNNYLIST_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "node.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int numOfNames = 4;
const int numOfColors = 4;
const int bunniesIni = 5;
const std::string colors[numOfColors] = {"Black", "White", "Brown", "Spotted"};
const std::string maleNames[numOfNames] = {"Joe", "Rafael", "Buby", "Messi"};
const std::string femaleNames[numOfNames] = {"Reichel", "Agnesa", "Mr Flufy", "Flower"};

class bunnyList{
private:
    node *head;
    int noOfBunnies;
    node *current, *prev;
public:

    bunnyList();

    void newBunny(std::string);
    void killHalfBunnies();
    void increaseAgeAndKill();
    void deleteNode();
    void breedBunnies();
    void setUp();

    int getRandomNumber(int) const;
    std::string getRandomColor();
    std::string getRandomName(bool);
    bool isMaleRandom();

    int getColonySize() const;
};

#endif
```

bunnyList.cpp:

```
#include "bunnyList.h"

bunnyList::bunnyList(){
        noOfBunnies = 0;
}

void bunnyList::setUp(){
        std::string temp = "";
        head = NULL;
        for(int i = 0; i <= bunniesIni; i++){
            newBunny(temp);
        }
}

void bunnyList::killHalfBunnies(){
    prev = head;
    current = head;

    while(noOfBunnies > 500){
        if(getRandomNumber(2) == 1){
            deleteNode();
            continue;
        } else if(current == NULL){
            current = head;
            prev = head;
       } else {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
            continue;
        }

    }
}

void bunnyList::newBunny(std::string color){
    node *bunny = new node();
    node *temp = head;

    if(color == ""){
        bunny->color = getRandomColor();
    } else {
        bunny->color = color;
    }

    bunny->isMale = isMaleRandom();
    bunny->name = getRandomName(bunny->isMale);
    bunny->age = 0;
    bunny->next = NULL;
    bunny->isBreedable = 0;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = bunny;
        return;
    }

    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    temp->next = bunny;
    noOfBunnies++;
}

void bunnyList::increaseAgeAndKill(){
    current = head;
    prev = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        current->age++;
        //Check if bunny can breed
        if(current->age > 2){
            current->isBreedable = 1;
        }
        //Check if its time to die :/
        if(current->age > 10){
            deleteNode();
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = head;
    prev = head;
}

void bunnyList::breedBunnies(){
    node *temp = head;
    bool oneMale = 0;
    int femaleCount = 0;
    //Check if there is at least one breedable male
    while(temp!=NULL){
        if(temp->isMale && temp->isBreedable){
            oneMale = 1;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    //For every female bunny over 2 years old a new bunny is born
    temp = head;
    if(oneMale){
    while(temp != NULL){
            if(temp->isMale == 0 && temp->isBreedable){
                newBunny(temp->color);
            }
        temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}

void bunnyList::deleteNode(){
    if(current==head){
        head = current->next;
        prev = head;
        delete current;
        current = head;
        noOfBunnies--;
    } else if(current->next==NULL){
        delete current;
        prev->next = NULL;
        prev = head;
        current = head;
        noOfBunnies--;
    } else {
        prev->next = current->next;
        current->next = NULL;
        delete current;
        current = prev->next;
        noOfBunnies--;
    }
}

std::string bunnyList::getRandomName(bool isMale){
    int r = getRandomNumber(numOfNames - 1);
    if(isMale)
    return maleNames[r];
    return femaleNames[r];
}

std::string bunnyList::getRandomColor(){
    int r = getRandomNumber(numOfColors - 1);
    return colors[r];
}

bool bunnyList::isMaleRandom(){
    if(getRandomNumber(2) == 1) {return true;}
    return false;
}

int bunnyList::getRandomNumber(int limit) const{
    return rand() % limit + 1;
}

int bunnyList::getColonySize() const{
    return noOfBunnies;
}
```

node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_INCLUDED
#define NODE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

class node {
    friend class bunnyList;
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string color;
    bool isMale;
    node *next;
    bool isBreedable;
public:
};

#endif // NODE_H_INCLUDED
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You didn't initialize head, current or prev in the constructor.  That is at least a severe style/maintainability flaw.  I didn't walk the code carefully enough to tell whether it is a definite bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for the review...

NEVER write `using namespace std`. Never. Just this morning there was a problem asked on SO where the reason for the issue at hand was that notorious line. I wonder who and why suggested that this is a good approach - there should be a book somewhere with this. If I had my way, it's author would be condemned to eternal manual removal of this line from every file.

Even without reading a line from the code, just by explanations alone, I know that the problem is most likely (100% likely, as in) to be related to memory management. You are freeing the memory which was not allocated properly, you are freeing the same memory twice or you are freeing something which was not allocated at all or you are accessing the memory after it was freed. Look at your `delete`s and check them.

On the style. Your code basically is an implementation of the business logic-aware list. Generally, this is not a good practice. It is much better to implement a generic list, supporting addition, deletion and other generic list operations, and than implement your business logic on top of this generic list.

Do not use `current` in your list. Instead, pass a node to be deleted in your delete function.

Lastly, run your program in the debugger and look into the variables you are deleting.

**EDIT**
Answering questions in commments.

Here is what I meant by business logic separation. There is a generic data structure, called list. It can be a list of anything, bunnies or space rockets, doesn't matter - but it still supports the basic list operations. Obviously, the two most important are insert and delete, but it is not the only operations for generic list. You can read wikipedia on list (data structure) for general ideas and look into std::list as in implementation. Now, you have your specific use case for list, a list of bunnies. For that specific use case you will add functionality on top of generic list. To clarify further, deleting an item from the list is something generic list supports. But 'killing a rabit' when the poor creature ages 10 years is something of the business logic. It contains iterating over list of rabbits (provided by generic list), checking age and making a decision to eliminate the creature (business-logic level) and than deleting the element (generic list). If this code were to be written using `std::list`, it would like approximately following:

```
std::list<Bunny> bunnies;
for (auto bunny = bunnies.cbegin(), end = bunnies.cend(); bunny != end; ++bunny) {
    if (bunny->age() > 10)
        bunny = bunnies.erase(bunny);
}
```

Comment: Great post by SergeyA.  Most likely current is going to NIL at some point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort by helping me. The thing I didn't understand completely was about those business logic-aware list and generic list, googled it but I didn't find anythink useful to read, could you take me on the right track? What should i put in google to read about them? Thank you.

Comment: @BeginnerSirius, added some details.

Answer (score 0):

I got a crash too.  It crashed in `deleteNode`, trying to reference `current->next` when `current` was NULL.

This was called from `bunnyList::killHalfBunnies`, in this code, which is the problem I find:

```
    if (getRandomNumber(2) == 1){
        deleteNode();
        continue;
    }
    else if (current == NULL){
        current = head;
        prev = head;
    }
```

The problem is you call `deleteNode`, which *assumes* that `current` is not NULL, *before* checking that `current` is in fact not NULL.  I rearranged the if's as shown here, and I'm no longer getting a crash:

```
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        current = head;
        prev = head;
    }
    else if (getRandomNumber(2) == 1)
    {
        deleteNode();
        continue;
    }
```

It would also be wise to put a check inside `deleteNode`, so that if it is called when `current` is NULL, it can handle it.  Possibly by throwing an exception or otherwise warning you.

Since you also asked about style:  comments in `deleteNode` (and elsewhere) would make it all clearer!

I assume this is a class assignment, and that's why you're not using `std::list`.